# Not able to retrieve data from mysql with string matching

Tags: mysql, select

```
mysql> select * from friends limit 10;
+----+------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | user                   | fri                     |
+----+------------------------+-------------------------+
                   |MHL_bKFgQ | NULL
 | 2 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | 8Y2EN4XNNhnwssuPb31sJg
 | 3 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | A1jPleJ99kXZ3t9wQ3np-g
 | 4 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | resYiOoGkQg6q0qgtj_1GA
 | 5 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | skl1OnkjMqD4GdFpVhU88Q
 | 6 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | 3Ss2aqrSoO7WbxE2GcLlfQ
 | 7 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | SGy3JDbhtzDTTBO7unqQxg
 | 8 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | Aez4Y1F0m2ucIfmfzPZfjw
 | 9 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | fT4jx_9cRWyKFROxv_MIrw
 |10 | MWhR9LvOdRbqtu1I_DRFBg | QmZOAYM7ITbTdkTn6ay_ag
+----+------------------------+-------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Command**:

```
mysql> select * from friends where fri="3Ss2aqrSoO7WbxE2GcLlfQ";
```

**Result**:

> Empty set (0.37 sec)

This is beyond my understanding. There is a valid data in the above table but when i try to retrieve it, it shows no rows.

Details of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE friends (
     id INT NOT NULL,
    user varchar(100) NOT NULL   ,
     fri varchar(100)    ,

 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: and if you do as `where trim(fri) = ` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use ENGINE=MyISAM;

Comment: What happens if you do:
 select * from friends where fri="SGy3JDbhtzDTTBO7unqQxg";

Comment: trim(fri) doesn't work. same with other also. Like is working. It looks like there is some extra character in the end but i m not able to see that

Comment: How are you inserting data?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: use load command in sql. My data is in csv

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. I have loaded my file with following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE friends fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
```

But the last column has ending  '\r\n'. So, \r was a garbage which was invisible. When i clean the file by removing \r using python, the SQL works as expected. Thank you guys for all your support.